# JavaScript get list of external scripts (like extensions)

Tags: javascript, html, browser-extension

Is it possible to get list of all scripts injected by browser? Or at least detect them somehow. I mean sometimes on Windows there are various viruses which inject scripts in fly modifying eg. click actions to display ads. I'm writing kind of advanced website so I'd like to warn user about other scripts which most likely:

1. will crash as my webapp is modifying basic native browser APIs like document.getElement* or even listeners
2. may make webapp unstable and in wors case make it crash.
3. could be performance overkill

I'm talking also about scripts modifying site content like eg. Ponify or XKCD numbers.
I know about navigator.plugins but it doesn't seem to be what am I looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. I mean you could do a:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('script');
```

And fetch all script tags, and check their `src` attribute, but it's not that simple.  It's possible to make an ajax request for a javascript file, and then `eval(ajaxResult)` to execute that code. Your browser has no way of knowing where that code came from as it's just a string.

There are a lot of ways to execute javascript, and cleanup any trace, there is no way to cover them all.

---

EDIT: I missed the key phrase "scripts injected by browser" :)

At least in Chrome, some extensions do seem to inject script tags. Though they don't seem to be marked up in any special way. Filtering them may be tricky. Perhaps if you add a `class` to the script tags you know should be there, and you find a script tag that does not have that class then you know it could be a extension script.

I'm also not sure that an extension *must* insert a script tag to do stuff on the page. I think it has ways of interacting with the page directly from the extension code as well. Not sure though. More research required. And this is probably different for different browsers.

---

Personally, I think defensively protecting your site from people's own browser extensions is a fools errand. If someone wants to hamstring their own browsing experience in bizarre ways, it's not your responsibility to hold their hand. And you will have a *very* hard time detecting all the ways an extension can blow up your everything.

Comment: seriously? O_o. Extensions are using just simple script tags? And they're visible inside document? I meant something like `document.styleSheets` which show also styles attached by extensions which are not present physically in document XML and don't have own tag

Comment: because for example I use only single script tag in document and all other scripts are loaded by eval so i guess extensions also don't need to use script tag?

Comment: are extensions run after website js or before? and are they using the same context as site JS? Because for example I'm removing Element.prototype.addEventListener at all (this webapp got internal sandbox) so if extensions use the same env as website and they don't use own copies of original APIs then they won't do any harm to my app

Comment: See my update. "are extensions run after website JS or before?" I think it depends on how the extension is setup. Extensions do lots of crazy things, some need to run before and some after.

Comment: i know. I'm going just to display some message in case I'll detect extensions just to make user aware that it's not our fault if his extensions will break something or will cause site so spam UI with error info popups. JS is smaller issue than custom CSS and actually styles can be detected reliably so I don't need super-hyper efficient script checking